# Where is the "Experience" Tab on Remote Desktop Connection for Mac

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, remote-connection

I am working on an EC2 instance through RDC (Server 2008 R2 SP1). In many places, I hear the "Experience Tab" referred to. Here's my question: **Where is the Experience tab** *or the equivalent thereof* **in Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection for Mac?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Preferences (⌘,) -> Display` is probably the closest thing, though I don't think they're exactly equivalent.

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to do: Have an EC2 server that I can see Aero over RDC. I fear its not possible.

Comment: Should have asked that in the original question! As far as I'm aware, Aero only works if the RDC client is in Windows, but I haven't tried it myself. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/06/23/aero-glass-remoting-in-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx might help). Also, there might be alternative RDC clients; you might want to ask a new SU question.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new here. Been over at Stack Overflow, but new here.